# ValueError: 'date' needs to be str

Tags: python, string, valueerror

I got a nice Python script, that will pull STYLE and YEAR based on MASTER release, with ARTIST+TITLE in mp3/flac as given input on autopilot from Discogs.

Using the frontend since backend needs ALBUM to be filled in proper.

All works, except when the value being pulled isn't there, which results in value: None.

Then, I get this ValueError: 'date' needs to be str error.

How to fix?

I've added str(year) which fixed it.

```
def write_tag_data(flacfile, style, year):
audio = FLAC(flacfile)
audio['genre'] = style
audio['date'] = str(year)
audio.save()
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the error with stack trace? That way we will see clearly where's the error.

Comment: Dumping code in stack overflow isn't a good way to ask questions

Comment: Who will read your code? Please post the relevant lines and error

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and adjust your question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your audio table saves date as string where as when you get year value, it is numeric and it remains as it there onwards.

Change the year value to int and then call the method write_tag_data.

Answer (score 0):

```
audio['date'] = str(year)
```

fixed it.